# React Native: Limit Swipes to Screen Borders with react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, scrollview

I'm working on a React Native app where I have a horizontal scrolling view using ScrollView wrapped in a PanGestureHandler from react-native-gesture-handler. I want to limit swipes to only be detected near the screen borders (left and right) and not from the center of the screen.

Here's my current code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, Animated, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { GestureHandlerRootView, PanGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { usePath } from '../../context';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const UserNavigator = () => {
    const { path, setPath } = usePath();
    const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);
    const translationX = new Animated.Value(0);
    const swipeThreshold = 100;

    const onSwipeGestureEvent = event => {
        const { velocityX, translationX: gestureTranslationX } = event.nativeEvent;

        if (Math.abs(velocityX) > swipeThreshold) {
            translationX.setValue(gestureTranslationX);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
            x: width,
            animated: false,
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView>
            <PanGestureHandler
                onGestureEvent={onSwipeGestureEvent}
                activeOffsetY={[]}
            >
                <Animated.View>
                    <ScrollView
                        ref={scrollViewRef}
                        horizontal
                        bounces={false}
                        pagingEnabled
                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                        className="w-full h-full bg-midnightBlack"
                    >
                        <View style={{ width, backgroundColor: 'red', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Text>Page 1</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ width, backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Text>Homepage</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ width, backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Text>Page 3</Text>
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                </Animated.View>
            </PanGestureHandler>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
};

export default UserNavigator;
```

I've tried adjusting the activeOffsetX values, but I'm still able to swipe from the center of the screen, which is causing issues. Can someone please provide guidance on how to correctly limit swipes to the screen borders?

Thank you!